# Multiple If function with priority

Tags: excel, formulas

I want an `If` function to have 2 criteria, where one segment takes priority. I don't know how to do that.

Currently I have

```
=IF($R145="Yes","Pending",IF($R145="No","x",IF($R145="","" or IF(ap145="Active","Completed",if(ap145="Pending","Completed")))))
```

I'd like the function after `or` to be read first and if it does not find it, it will work based on the formula before the `or`. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your logic but here is a rearranged version of what you had with the or function corrected:

```
=IF($R145="Yes","Pending",IF($R145="No","x",OR(IF
(AP145="Active","Completed",IF(AP145="Pending","Completed")),IF($R145="",""))))
```

Maybe that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

`=IF(AP145="Active","Completed",IF(AP145="Pending","Completed",IF($R145="Yes","Pending",IF($R145="No","x",""))))`

This formula does the following steps:

- AP145, does it equal 'Active'?  If Yes, then "Completed".  If No, next bullet.
- AP145, does it equal 'Pending'?  If Yes, then "Completed".  If No, next bullet.
- $R145, does it equal 'Yes'? If Yes, then "Pending".  If No, next bullet.
- $R145, does it equal 'No'? If Yes, then "x".  If No, then display `""` (blank).

[image: If Statement]